# Youtube: add part of live stream a item to playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I need to create a playlist on Youtube with highlights from a livestream; I thought I can add them via API and the ``` startA`` and ```endA`` properties, but it seems as if Youtube removed that feature:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/youtube/Gipu_cCDScI

If I add playlistitems via API and set both properties, the item is added in full length to the playlist.

Is there any possibility to add only a part of the livestream video to the playlist? Cropping manually or whatever, I just need to create a highlights-playlist...

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the current APIs. Usually when the stream ends the entire video of the livestream is uploaded to the user's channel. If you want to read more about the [life of a broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast#intro), you can check out the documentation

Answer (score 0):

This featured was deprecated with the v2 API without replacement int he v3 API.  You will have to manually download the video of the Live Event, cut up the video with your favorite editor, re-upload the newly cut video, and add that to a playlist.